# SFML: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF9CB4682CD(ntdll.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

У меня возникла проблема, следующий код компилируется и запускается, но сразу же после запуска вызвывается исключение.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

class A{
public:
  A() {
    rend();
  }

  void rend() {
    RenderTexture r; //исключение возникает в этом месте
  }
}
A a = A();
```

Вот и само исключение:

[image: Исключение Visual Studio]

Я использую библиотеку [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) версии 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил SFML до версии 2.5.0, больше исключение не появлялось